# Некорректный слайдер

Tags: javascript, html, css

Переделываю слайдер под себя, и заметил одну проблему.
Она заключается в том, что когда перелистываешь слайд, каждый последующий слайд будет перелистываться всё быстрее.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides() {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    setTimeout(showSlides, 5000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

```css
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */


/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-zen_doc/1898210/pub_5cd17cbea682f400afb9c822_5cd17ede0ae27d00b35e968f/scale_1200" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
  <img src="https://memepedia.ru/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/memy-pro-volkov-5.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
  <img src="https://www.meme-arsenal.com/memes/b079669e0b2841b51751296a9c601c3c.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
</div>
```

Comment: `dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");` зачем делать такое, когда есть встроенные методы работы с классами? Например `dots[i].classList.remove("active");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var timer;
function showSlides() {
    ...
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(showSlides, 5000);
}
```

Comment: Это оказалось проще, чем я думал. Благодарю вас!

Comment: @Kugasu откуда то копируешь и вставляешь не вникаясь в детали? просто реально страшно смотреть на эти 20+- строк кода

Comment: Вы сильно не пугайтесь, я всего лишь студент, которому нужно сделать курсовую.
Само собой над более серьёзными работами я подобным заниматься не собираюсь.